# Split String in flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I using split method to split the `String`.

```
String date = "2020-10-07";
date.split("-");
print("split " + date[0]);
```

I expect will get 2020, but why it return 2 ?

Comment: Your `date` is still a String. Yo should assign the return value of `::split` to an array var.

Comment: @AndrewCheong I actually reading this https://www.tutorialkart.com/dart/dart-split-string/. The String will become `list` after using `split`, no?

Comment: Nope, in that reference you also see it returning a list of strings.

Comment: You are still using the same date object it is `immutable` use `print( date.split('-')[0]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting 2 is because it is the first position (0) of the string variable `date`.

When you split a string, it will return a list/array.

```dart
String date = "2020-10-07";
final dateList = date.split("-");
print("split " + dateList[0]);
//expected "split 2020"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is 2 because there no change has been done to the variable date( the same without the split), but with [split](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html) you can access the list like this below

```
String date = "2020-10-07";
var first = date.split("-").first;//returns the first element of the list
print("split " + first);
```

Answer (score 1):

`(Any String)`.split(`Pattern`) returns `List<String>`.
Since no operation was done to change the variable (it anyhow can't store `List<String>`).

You are left with:

1. Temporarily store the split as @Morgan Hunt and @Henok Suggested
2. print("split " + `date.split("-").first`); (I guess you are going to return the first split)

Also `data[0]` -> is an operation on a string hence you are getting 0th position  -> `2`